# Is this right usage Of factory method

Tags: java, design-patterns, graph, factory-pattern

As i understood Factory design pattern is used to create object instead of constructors

in a previous question i  explained my situation which is :
I have a complex Network represented as hypergraph
Hypergraph vertices are from various type :image,tag ....
I should create thousand of vertices
it will be hard to create it manually!
so i thought that factory pattern may help me in this case

I drew two possible diagram using yUML but i can't decide what is the most appropriate to my situation

[image: first diagram]

[image: second diagram]

Comment: Nice images. However it's hard to tell without looking at some code. (Actually I have to admit I don't fully understand how you would implement it in the second case - but the diagram sure looks simpler.)

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd diagram. How do you propose to return TagVertex and ImageVertex from the same `createVertex()` method that takes no arguments ?

Comment: @Axel i think i will found others problems when I start to write some code :)

Comment: @DeepakBala , no it will take the vertex type as argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both depict the Factory Method pattern.

But, as we are speaking of mutiple factories, the first image is a better, less coupled, more extensible, easier to maintain approach.

Just, in the first image, as you have a yet small diagram, it is better to put a dashed line from `AbstractVertexFactory` to `Vertex`, as there is a [dependency relationship](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398623&seqNum=12) between these classes.

Also, the second image is missing all the dashed dependency lines. This **does not make this diagram incorrect**, and it still does depict the factory method pattern, the only drawback is that it is more confusing without the mentioned lines.

**Explanation of why the first is better than the second**:

- **Less coupled**: In the first case, if you change/delete the `TagVertex`, no clients of the `ImageFactory` (and potetially other factories) are affected.
- **More extensible** and **easier to maintain**: Same principle. If you change a product (`Vertex` in your scenario) class, no client of other factory is affected. Also you can add factories freely without need to change existing code.

Comment: It would be good if you explain why 1st image is better than 2nd.

Comment: Did it. Is it good? Be honest, if not good enough, I can elaborate more.

Comment: this model is based on the official GoF Factory Method UML diagram
there is no dotted line between AbstractProduct which is the Vertex in my case and the AbstractFactory

Comment: In UML, the dotted line means "depends on". "Depends on" means: if you change one, you'll potentally have to change another (or at least you should check it). `AbstractVertexFactory` clearly depends on `Vertex`.

Comment: Also, as dependency relations between classes are very common, one may choose to omit them in certain cases (as the diagram would become a crazy spaghetti of dashed lines). GoF chose to omit them. I wouldn't, though, as your diagram is very small.

Comment: createVertex is an abstract method that return Vertex object 
i can't see where is the dependency betweeb them

Comment: Simple: change `Vertex`'s name to `Vortex`. It is a silly example, but simply importing a class is enough to create a dependency relationship. You just may choose not to depict it in your diagram.

Comment: @acdcjunior : I don't think that AbstractVertexFactory depends on Vertex.It is concrete factory classes that make use of Vertex (by creating concrete classes).AbstractVertexFactory doesn't even know which concrete vertex object is being returned.

Comment: Just edited the answer. I agree the dependency is a very broad relationship and can be used in almost any place. Nevertheless, it can, sometimes, be useful (your second image do not have any dependency line and people may think the concrete factory does not have any relationship with the product class, as it clearly must and do have).

Comment: @Atul, yes, it does not need to know which `Vertex` object is being returned. But, still, it does need to know the `Vertex` class. The dependency relationship is an UML relationship between two nodes (two classes in our case, but can be packages or other stuff) that means: "a change in the supplier could affect the client." As I said, just importing the class (and not even using it) is enough to create a dependency relationship. How? Try deleting the imported class. Will the importer still compile (with no changes)?

Comment: @acdcjunior:I agree about dependency concept and explanation also given above in case of this example.I was considering "dependency" in a broader context. (the explanation i gave in above post)

Comment: I have another question:
 Vertex class has two attribute :"id" of integer type and "value"
the type of "value" argument is different for each concret vertex 
should I use generic type in such case

Comment: Yes. You can use `Object` as it's type, but, if you can, generics are preferable (as they will allow stronger typing).

Answer (score 2):

Diagram one is the correct option.

Abstract factory is used to create families of related or dependent objects.
In this case , Abstract veretx factory (through use of Tag or Image factory concrete classes )will create concrete products (Tag Vertex and Image vertex )
respectively.

In case of second diagram , there is no relation between products and abstract factory. 
Abstract factory should create the concrete products (by making use of concrete factory classes Image Vertex and Tag Vertex in this case)